# Identify regex paterns except certain symbols

Tags: python, regex

I am currently using the following regex pattern to remove the symbols in the sentence.

```
sentence = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", sentence)
```

However, I want to keep all the `-` and remove all the other symbols in the sentences.

For example in the below mentioned sentence I want to get the output as follows.

```
Input: tim-tam is a tasty, yummy chocolate.
Output: tim-tam is a tasty yummy chocolate
```

How can I improve my current regex pattern to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

`[^a-zA-Z]` means match any character that is not in the range a-z or A-Z.

> Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing the set. If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters that are not in the set will be matched. For example, [^5] will match any character except '5', and [^^] will match any character except '^'. ^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the set.

If you want to also exclude `-`, include it: `[^a-zA-Z-]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I will accept this as the answer. Suppose, I want to neglect `'` appear before `s`, Is it correct to write it as [^a-zA-Z-'s]? E.g., Input: `dog's 'food' is finish` Output: `dog's food is finish`

Comment: No. That will be a more complicated pattern. `[]` indicates a set of characters. You could accomplish that with a negative lookahead (look for it in the documentation linked in my answer). For example: `[^a-zA-Z-']|'(?!s)`. The `'(?!s)` part matches a `'` not followed by a `s`. The `|` means or.

Answer (score 0):

[^a-zA-Z-]

Anything but a-z, A-Z or dash.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your current regex

```
sentence = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", sentence)
```

and you want to exclude `-`, use

```
sentence = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z-]"," ", sentence)
```

The caret at the beginning of `[]` means "not in this character class". Therefore, adding `-` to the set excludes it from the match.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Suppose, I want to neglect `'` appear before `s`, Is it correct to write it as [^a-zA-Z-'s]? E.g., Input: `dog's 'food' is finish` Output: `dog's food is finish`